# Could "$g(a)≠0$" change into "$ \lim_{x \to a} g(x) ≠ 0$"?

Tags: limits

If $f$ and $g$ are polynomials, with $g(a)≠0$, then $ \lim_{x \to a}  \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}  = \frac{f(a)}{g(a)}$.

Could "$g(a)≠0$" change into "$ \lim_{x \to a} g(x) ≠ 0$"?

[image]

Comment: This is very difficult to read.

Comment: Well, you can make the change, but it does exclude cases.  Consider $f(x) = x^3$ and $g(x) = x^2$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.  Does that work in the first form?  In the second?

Comment: I don't see any difference because for polynomial $g(x) $ we have $g(a) =\lim_{x\to a} g(x) $. It is same as saying : can we replace $2$ by $20/10$?

Comment: Please visit the [mathjax tutorial especially written for beginners](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site) and try to typeset math using it.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor: why does it exclude cases? The example you point out neither works in first form nor in second form because $g(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=0$.

Comment: Try to reformulate the question. It's not clear. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f(x) = x^3$ and $g(x) = x^2$.
Then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = x$.

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} x = 0$ which is perfectly well defined.

But if you require $g(0) \neq 0$, then that is an extra requirement you are adding and you have ruled out the example that works under the first definition.